# Can't add vertex to polygon in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, vector-layer, vertices

I'm working in QGIS3.8.3 and am trying to use the Vertex Tool to add a vertex to a pre-existing polygon. I expect to be able to do this in an editing session by hovering over the segment in question and selecting an x, but no x appears and I'm only able to move existing vertices. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try running Fix Geometries against it to see if it behaves after that?

Comment: Did you try double clicking on the segment?

Comment: are the vertices very close together? you might need to zoom in until they're further apart so you can see the x (or +) to create a new vertex.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! In _Settings_ menu, _Options_, _Digitizing_ tab, if you define a _Search radius for vertex edit_ = 0, you will not be able to select a vertex or segment, and only right click over a feature will open the coordinates panel for the _Vertex Tool_. Have you defined a radius = 0 in that option?

Comment: My Search radius for vertex edit = 1, and the problem persists: still no crosshairs that I can select to add a vertex to my polygon.